# Keyboard lights turn on when device is off

Tags: laptop, keyboard, plugins, charger, intel

My laptop's keyboard lights on when I plug in the charger but the device is off I didn't turn it on although the keyboard light turn on
It still on even I unplug the charger
What is wrong with it?
My laptop is Intel whitebook LAPQC71B
Please help thank you